# Evaluating the integral $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} 11 \sqrt{\sec^2\theta-1}\,d\theta$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Evaluating the integral $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} 11 \sqrt{\sec^2\theta-1}\,d\theta$.

Recall that $\tan^2\theta+1=\sec^2\theta \iff \sec^2\theta-1=\tan^2\theta$. So,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} 11 \sqrt{\sec^2\theta-1}\,d\theta
& = 11 \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \sqrt{\tan^2\theta}\,d\theta \\
& = 11 \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \tan\theta\,d\theta \\
& = 11 \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\,d\theta \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Let $u=\cos\theta$, $\,du=-\sin\theta\,du$.
Hence
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& = -11 \int \dfrac{\,du}{u} \\
& = -11 \left. \ln|\cos \theta|\right]_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \\
& = -11 (\ln|\cos (pi/4)| - \ln|\cos (-pi/4)|) \\
& = -11 (\ln|\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}| - \ln|\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}|) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
which equals 0 but the textbook says the answer is $11\ln 2$. Where did I mess up?

Comment: Note $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$. So you should have $\sqrt{\tan^2\theta}=|\tan \theta|$, otherwise you started out with an even function and missing this step has resulted in $\tan \theta$, which is an odd function.

Comment: Are you sure about that $11$? It looks so silly…

Comment: @AnuragA Yes you are right. I am tutoring Cal 2 and I, of course, forget one of the many tricks. Thank you I got it!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes i am sure. The constant is randomly generated and I got 11. It's fun looking on my paper and seeing $11\cdot \ln$ hehe

Comment: @BarryCipra You're right! I fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} 11 \sqrt{\sec^2\theta-1}\,d\theta
& = 11 \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \sqrt{\tan^2\theta}\,d\theta \\
& = 11 \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \lvert\tan\theta\rvert\,d\theta \\
& = 2\cdot11\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \tan\theta\,d\theta \\
& = 22[-\log(\cos \theta)]_{0}^{\pi/4}=22(-\log(\cos(\pi/4))+\log(\cos0))  \\
& = 22\frac{\log 2}{2}=11\log 2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}